# How to create Multi site without create duplicate table in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, multisite

How to create Multi site network without create table like (wp_1_post). I need to data own Wordpress table No need to create new table.

Because I have 10000 or More Users. If all user create his sub domain then Coming a Problem. 10000*9 = 90000 Table will created in my database and it's very difficult to handle all table.

So it's very Difficult. Please help me to solve this Problem.

Comment: Creating multi sites in wordpress creates separate tables. This is hardcoded in wordpress. Either you need to hack wordpress or you might end up creating your own CMS for that.

Comment: If I am creating My Own CMS Then it's taking too much time. Can I Customization in database like channelize and we change query in wordpress.  Please Help  me if you have idea regarding database channelize.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your users to create sub sites, change their roles to those which don't have the privilege to do it. How can you create subsites when you don't have any associated tables to store it's data?

Comment: I need to create Sub site but Without Creating table's

Comment: If there are no tables associated with a subsite, where will you save the subsite details? And don't you want to create posts in the subsite?

Comment: can we store data on which is created table's Like wp_post without create new table

Comment: If 10000 User Create his own sub site then create 90000 table's automatically

Comment: the data in a sub site can be saved in the tables corresponding to it only.

Comment: If you have any Idea regarding this Flow  then Please help me

Comment: https://prague.wordcamp.org/2014/files/2014/02/Tom_Eagles-WPMU.pdf. Please refer possible workarounds at 'WPMU Database Issues and
Management' section.